# Probability and Bake Cookies

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Dean bakes cookies. He made a mixture for $120$ cookies and inside the mixture he put $150$ chocolate chips. 
If the chocolate chips distribute by Poisson, what is the expected value $E(x)$ of the chocolate cookies in a cookie?

So Do I just do Poisson distribution formula here? I'm not sure because I don't have the lambda, and the lambda itself in Poisson is the expected value.

Comment: $\frac{150}{120}=1.25$

Comment: It seems to me that *regardless* of the distribution they follow... you have $150$ chocolate chips and $120$ cookies.  There would be an average of $\dfrac{150}{120}$ chips per cookie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\lambda$ paramter can be calculated dividing the total cookies by the total bakes, so your $\lambda = \frac{150}{120}=1.25$ that is also your expectation